# Is it too late to study physics?

Tags: soft-question, education

I'm 24 year old student and I study Bachelor's degree of information technology. This is my last year there.

Before I applied to this school I didn't know (remember) anything about mathematics or physics, but nevertheless I got in and after that I studied especially physics and mathematics. I had the best teachers I could hope for. They made me realize how much I love physics and math and now I have top grades in both. My GPA is 4/5.

Is it too late to study physics (career-wise)? If not, then when is it too late? I want to study M.Sc. or Ph.D. degree, but I'd be 25 years old when I apply and when I would graduate I would be 30 years old. By the way, what are the differences in M.Sc. or Ph.D degrees in physics?

Also are there any good tips what to study for the entrance examination? Maybe some good text books to study? I have few text books that I plan to read and I might also check Khan Academy videos.

Comment: Not a very typical one to be honest. I'm also not 100% sure if this is on topic.

Comment: @gonenc It's boarderline in my opinion because it's so specific to this one user's experience. A more widely applicable question about the prerequisites at each stage of study might be better. This post also asks too many different questions. As I remind people all the time, a Physics Stack Exchange post should ask one question.

Comment: @DanielSank: OP could come to chat actually; for now there are many caveats: too many questions, _too broad_, _primarily opinion-based_ are some grounds on which it can be closed.

Comment: @user36790 I agree chat is the place for this but note OP's reputation level.

Comment: @DanielSank: Yes, but apart from the chat, I don't deem it as an apt question here.

Comment: @user36790 Agreed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about career advice, not physics.

Comment: @gonenc and others: if you ask me, this is _way_ off topic. I'd also remind everyone that comments are not to be used for answering the question.

Comment: To be fair, this is also a duplicate of [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7327/) (also rightfully closed as off-topic).

Comment: @DanielSank Note that [career advice is off-topic!](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4768/redundant-tags-vote).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Definitely not too late! I've known graduate students in physics entering anywhere between 20 and 30, and I know there are even older and younger out there. Even better, it's not like information technology is a completely irrelevant- in physics (particularly high energy physics) we routinely deal with big data and I'm sure you could apply some of what you learned there.

If you've kept up in physics and mathematics, that's a good thing as well. As far as entrance examinations go, I would recommend looking up what textbooks your university of choice assigns their undergraduate physics majors, and think about studying that.

The difference between the M.S. and Ph.D. varies a little bit, but generally the M.S. is a short program mainly based on coursework (though there may be a thesis as well) and the Ph.D. is a much longer program that universally requires a lengthy dissertation.

Answer (score 7):

If I compare your case (which is similar to mine) I will graduate when I'm 27 and then I can start a phd so i will be 31 years young :) If you love what you do, just do it ! eventually it will be worth it !

Answer (score 6):

I *begun* a Computer science degree at 24, and at the end of the first year I decided that I really liked studying Physics far more than IT. I wanted to switch to a physics degree but I wasn't qualified enough and had to do a year long science foundation program first. Undeterred, I took the course and 5 Years later I had an MSC in Physics. Last year (after a year working), I begun a PhD in theoretical physics - I am 31.

It's not too late :)

Good luck.